# apt-get rollback version not found

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

I need to rollback some packages. I have a list of all the packages I need to rollback and the versions I need. All the versions I need are sitting in `/var/cache/apt/archives` yet apt ignored them telling me that it couldn't find the version I asked for. How can I get apt to see the older versions? I did try using dpkg-scanpackages but it seems to ignore the older ones favoring the newer ones. The command I used is `apt-get -s install $(cat rollback.txt | tr '\n' ' ')`. `rollback.txt` contains all of the packages I wish to downgrade in the correct apt format. [rollback.txt](https://dl.scoopta.ninja/rollback.txt). The errors are linked here: [errors.log](https://dl.scoopta.ninja/errors.log). I'm basically looking to downgrade of everything from today. I'll then go through and do an upgrade that won't brick my system.

Comment: Tell us what commands you used, along with the results, including error messages. And it's downgrade, not rollback.

Comment: @FaheemMitha alright I updated the post

Comment: You'll have to force downgrades. Apt isn't going to downgrade otherwise. And note that Debian doesn't officially support downgrades, though it's possible to downgrade if you are careful and know what you are doing. I once walked a guy through a mass downgrade over Unix SE chat. What packages are you trying to downgrade? If it's a long list, what's the number of packages? Also, why are you trying to downgrade these packages? Some context might be helpful.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I'm running the AMDGPU-PRO drivers under debian sid and the latest upgrade completely bricked my drivers. The drivers are only supported on Ubuntu, SLES, RHEL, and CentOS but it's important that I use them and not Mesa because I'm one of the few people who game on Linux and Mesa performance is terrible. Also my original post has a list of the packages I'm trying to downgrade. I don't need to downgrade all of them but I figured it'd be less of a headache to do that and then upgrade carefully from there.

Comment: More context. What was this upgrade? Are you running testing/unstable, or something else? Also, do you have any idea what caused the breakages? Packages related to the kernel and/or X would be my first guesses. That's a long list of packages. Maybe start with downgrading a single package to make sure it works. Run `apt-cache policy pkgname` to see the available versions.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I noted in my last comment that I'm running sid(unstable). Anyway it isn't a kernel package because I compile my own kernels. It's probably an X11 or gnome package that caused the problem but either way my problem still stands. If I do `apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-video-all` the only version that's listed is 7.7+18 when I need 7.7+16. However inside of `/var/cache/apt/archives` I have 2 debs one for +16 and one for +18 and this is the problem I have with all packages. I have the packages I need but apt doesn't see them.

Comment: Ah, an unstable upgrade. You shouldn't run unstable unless you really need to. Or are an expert. Apt won't see packages in your local archive, that's correct. One option is to use snapshot.debian.org if you want to go back to an earlier version, assuming you know what that is.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I switched to Sid for two reasons. The first of which is the newer version of gnome. God is Jessie's outdated. That and the newer versions of the drivers don't work on Jessie. Granted they don't work on Sid at the moment either but they did.

Comment: Fair enough. I suggest you pick a package to downgrade, then add the Debian sources from snapshot.debian.org for that package, then try to force a downgrade. FWIW, I don't think Gnome would cause a driver breakage. There are alternatives to this (e.g. running `dpkg -i` on your archived debs), but that one, at least, won't work well in general. BTW, if you want to have a conversation about this, the [U&L chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat) would be better. You could ping me there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50575/discussion-between-scoopta-and-faheem-mitha).

Comment: Hi Scoopta, I prefer to use the main chat room. SE likes to create separate short-lived rooms per question, but I think it's silly. If/when you're there, ping me. I might be afk or asleep, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must correct me. In /var/cache/apt/archives

`dpkg-scanpackages -m ./ /dev/null | gzip > Packages.gz`

> The parameter -m means -m, --multiversion Include all found packages
>   in the output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it also works for you this way. `cat /path/to/rollback.txt | xargs apt-get install --reinstall` on a System with full root-acount.

With sudo `cat /path/to/rollback.txt | xargs sudo apt-get install`

Maybe you need the option -y for apt, I can not remember. But with the option -y apt-get will install a once without any questioning.

This answer can here not work.

I would do it with aptoncd.  With that Programm you can create an iso which can be use with apt-cdrom so you can use it as sources.

create temporaly an entry in /etc/fstab  `/dev/sr0       /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0` and `mkdir /media/cdrom`

Create an iso. `udisksctl loop-setup -f /path/to/aptoncd-iso` as user, be  attentive  to what loop-device the iso ist mapped. 
As root or with sudo `mount /dev/loop? /media/cdrom` Then `apt-cdrom -m add`
and apt `update` and then try again `cat /path/to/rollback.txt | xargs apt-get install --reinstall` I know it is a long way. Then you achive your goal, then comment the enty in /etc/fstab out. This is important and the new Entry in sources.list too

Comment: Yeah the problem isn't that it won't install them, it's that it says it can't find the versions I specified but all of the versions it says it can't find are sitting in the apt cache. I just can't figure out why it's ignoring them.

Comment: Hm, can you show `apt-cache policy base-files` ? Maybe your Versions are not longer availible in the package sources .

Comment: the only version listed is 9.7 which is the one currently installed however if I go to `/var/cache/apt/archives` and do `ls -l | grep base-files` it shows two different `.deb` files. One is 9.7 the other is 9.6 yet it tells me it can't find version 9.6 and that's the mystery I'm trying to solve. I have all the older packages but apt can't find them.

Comment: It doesn't matter for apt what it is in his cache. it draws it's Informations what is availible from your sources and store it under  `/var/lib/apt/lists/*`

Comment: interesting. What can I do then? Is there a way to have dpkg-scanpackages scan all versions not just the latest or?

Comment: `cd /var/cache/apt/archives` then create `dpkg-scanpackages ./ /dev/null | gzip > Packages.gz` In /etc/apt/sources.list `deb file:/var/cache/apt/archives` It is not enough to create Packages.gz. Apt have to know there the Packages is and the creating file lies, so you need an entry in the sources.list.

Comment: I did that but it seems like dpkg-scanpackages only indexes the newest packages and ignores older ones.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50568/discussion-between-bahamut-and-scoopta).